# How to setup rethinkdb proxy server

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-javascript

we have two client machines, how do we connect both of them using proxy server? As you said earlier:
"To start a RethinkDB proxy on the client:
rethinkdb proxy -j -j ..."
only of the clients can connect in this way, since the ports will already be in use.

Comment: Could you share more about how your architecture is setup @hellodk?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned elsewhere, you can avoid the port conflict by passing in the `-o 1` argument. This shifts the ports that the proxy uses by an offset of 1.